# Android R.java file exists but problems when building in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I could build my Android project in Eclipse without any issues until I renamed the package for my activity.

I moved the activity file from

```
com.example.MainActivity
```

to

```
com.example.activity.MainActivity
```

I then proceeded to update the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to reflect the proper class name for the activity. This is what my `.classpath` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Whenever I try to build my project, it says

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

The funny thing is that `R.java` DOES exist in the `gen` folder and it always gets generated even after I perform a `clean`. This only started happening AFTER I changed the package name. I've taken a look at some open source application which store their `Activities` in a separate folder too and they all import com.example.R.

So if I decide to put my Activity classes in `com.example.activity` instead of `com.example`, do I have to manually import `com.example.R` everytime?

Comment: Wherever you seem to use it now you need to import R

Answer (score 1):

Rename it using Eclipse Refactor utility.

Right Click on package name -- > Select Refactor -> Rename.

Rename the package name. Eclipse will automatically update all the references for this package.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

```
if I decide to put my Activity classes in "com.example.activity" instead of "com.example", do I have to manually import com.example.R everytime?
```

Manual import of R ....No...

Possible solution:-

- Check for your layouts are there any problems there like you have use
  Customize button in com.example.CustomizeButton and defined in your
  layout now as package has chaged make sure the identifier is correct
  in .xml as well..
- Also check the Problem section, you get some idea... Window-->Show
  View --> Problems..
- Check for old reference in your Manifest file as well
- Clean and build your project (Needless to say... :P)
- Restart the eclipse as last resort b'coz it forces the workspace to
  build again

Comment: I think if there are problems in your layout, R.java is not even generated. I mentioned that R.java does in fact exist, I just had to import it into my Activity classes each time when previously I did not. So I realized this happened because the package name for the 2 classes were now different since I moved the Activity class

Answer (score 0):

Bah! My brain must have been fried, can't believe I missed this. So yes, I do have to manually import R.java now since it's in a different package from the one my activities are in. Previously I did not have to do that because R.java and MainActivity.java were both under com.example. Now R.java is in

```
com.example
```

while MainActivity.java is in

```
com.example.activity
```

Comment: if you like i would post that as an answer for you to accept?